# Nuget.exe not picking up App_Start folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, webactivator

Has anyone experienced problems when NuGet pack command doesn't pick up the `/App_Start` or `/content/App_Start` folders where we put our `.pp` files for use with the [WebActivator](https://bitbucket.org/davidebbo/webactivator/wiki/Home) package?
I have to open the package with Package Explorer and then manually add the desired folders and files, which is troublesome.

Comment: What concrete set of steps do you take a create your package?

Comment: nuget spec, nuget pack project.csproj (the project does include the folders that are missing in the nupkg file)

Comment: When packing from a project, only files that are in the project and are marked as content are added.

Comment: Thanks, marking Build Action as Content did the trick. Though I guess it should work without that since the files were included in the project. Experiencing kinda strange VS behaviour lately..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dfowler suggests, it only includes files that are in the project. In the project, try clicking View All Files, and then include the relevant .pp file, with a build action of 'Content'.

As an alternative, you can explicitly list those files in the nuspec file and they will be included.

Comment: Thanks, marking Build Action as Content did the trick. Though I guess it should work without that since the files were included in the project. Experiencing kinda strange VS behaviour lately..also I would want to avoid the .nuspec files as much as possible.